# How can I remove values less than a certain number from a list of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataset that is a list of arrays. Each array is a 30s trial, and within each array is a list of times of events that occurred in the trial over 30s. So for example, one array would be [0.2, 3., 5., 6.2,.....29.99].

I want to plot only the events that occurred in the first 10s of each trial using eventplot. This is what I have tried:

`plt.eventplot(test_spikes[test_spikes<10]);`

But I get the error "'<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: "I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong". Well, what does the error message say you are trying to compare? A `list` and an `int`, yes? Using `<` this way is a special Numpy thing, right? So, is `data` *supposed to* be a plain Python list? Now go check why it is, and fix that.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for your response. I'm really new to coding, so I'm a bit unclear what you mean. My understanding is that the data I have is a list of arrays, with each array containing float values less than 30. I imported the data from as such:
`data = np.load('class5_data.npz', allow_pickle = True)
test_spikes = data['test_spikes'].tolist()`.

Comment: Right; you should have a single (2-dimensional) array instead. Don't `tolist` it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
[d for d in data if d < 10]
```

Comment: so for my data titled test_spikes, it would be plt.eventplot(test_spikes for test_spikes in test_spikes if test_spikes<10)?

Comment: no, eventplot( [t for t in test_spikes if t < 10] )

Answer (score 0):

You have first to convert to numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=20,size=(50,))
# data = np.array(data) # not necessary as it is a numpy array
print(data.shape)   # (50,)
plt.eventplot(data[data<10])
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: this gives the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: For that one, please search the site; there are many duplicate questions.

Comment: @applej7 How does your `data` look like. I have taken the example of you question. For that the code works without any arror. But if you have another kind of list, please share.

Comment: @CodePope thanks for the response! I imported the data as follows: 'data = np.load('class5_data.npz', allow_pickle = True) test_spikes = data['test_spikes'].tolist()' And am trying to perform the eventplot function on test_spikes. I just simplified it to data in the original question

Comment: And what is the shape of `data`? And by the way, you don't need to convert it a list (`tolist`). It is always better to directly work with the numpy array you just import with `np.load`. Numpy is much faster in many tasks that the python `list`.

Comment: The shape is (50,)

Comment: @applej7 I have updated the code to show you that the code works perfectly fine. There most be information that is missing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a list of (what I assume are) `numpy` arrays, you need to perform your comparison for each array individually. The error message is trying to tell you this; the outer list is not a numpy array and therefore does not support comparison with an integer.

```
to_plot = [x[x<10] for x in test_spikes]
```

For this to work, x must be `np.array`s. If that is not given, you can convert them as such:

```
test_spikes = [np.array(x) for x in test_spikes]
```